# Mysql Count Week Total of Current Month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to COUNT my data week by week current month.

For example;

Today is 25th of June.

We are on the last week of this month. So must be the 4th week of this month.

1. Week Total = 3125
2. Week Total = 7542
3. Week Total = 4565
4. Week Total = 1111 (Current week).

When july starts, we will get only first week. (Let's pretend we are in the 3rd day of july)

1. Week Total = 700

Any idea?

I did this for day of weeks but didn't get it work with the month.

Week example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as day_total, DATE(`date`) as week_day 
FROM edp_orders 
WHERE DATE(`date`) > DATE(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
GROUP BY DATE(`date`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT yearweek(`date`), 
       @n := @n + 1 as week_number,
       COUNT(id) as week_total
FROM edp_orders 
CROSS JOIN (select @num := 0) n
WHERE year(`date`) = year(curdate()) 
AND  month(`date`) = month(curdate()) 
GROUP BY yearweek(`date`)
```

Comment: This is getting the week total. I want to get every week seperated (grouped by week number). :(

Comment: You mean mine was getting the month total. I updated the answer.

Comment: Okay this is better but can you get the number of the week based on the current month? 1, 2, 3, 4?